# macOS 10.12.4 NSButton After adding CAGradientLayer, button title is not displayed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

The purpose of the following code is to achieve a gradient background color
In newer versions, it looks fine, but in macOS 10.12.4, the title of the button doesn't appear

```
- (void)setGradient:(NSArray<__kindof NSColor *> *)colorArr StartPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint EndPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint {
    self.wantsLayer = YES;
    CAGradientLayer *gradinentlayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSColor *color in colorArr) {
        [array addObject:(id)color.CGColor];
    }
    gradinentlayer.colors = array;
    gradinentlayer.startPoint = startPoint;
    gradinentlayer.endPoint = endPoint;
    gradinentlayer.frame = self.bounds;
    [self.layer insertSublayer:gradinentlayer atIndex:0];
}
```

How do I make the title text appear, other than adding a subview?

Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried :

```
self.layer = gradinentlayer;
```

But this invalidates the layer's other Settings,This is not in line with expectations

Comment: Could you iterate the subviews and layers of the button? And see if the hierarchy is different with the two macOS versions?

Comment: @Larme I wish I could iterate through layers of buttons, but I can't find a way, I'm not sure if Apple has an API for printing these

Comment: There is `self.layer.sublayers`, and do it also for each views of the NSButton?

Comment: @Larme On macOS 10.12.4, the output is:
(
    "<CAGradientLayer: 0x60800002ff00>"
)

On macOS 12.4, the output is:
(
    "<CAGradientLayer: 0x6000003d05c0>",
    "<NSTextLayer: 0x600000d0ddd0>"
)

Comment: So where is the title on 10.12.4? Is it a subview?

Comment: @Larme No, it's the NSButton property button.title. In newer versions, there will be an NSTextLayer, but in macOS 10.12.4 there is no NSTextLayer. 
If the gradient is not set, it will display normally, but with the gradient set, the title will not display in macOS 10.12.4